# How to implement IoT in serial communication devices

Tags: iot, azure-iot-hub

I want to enable IoT in the devices (inverters) which currently supports only serial communication. Through serial port I'm able to view statistics of the device, configure device and do firmware updates. I want to do all these remotely by enabling IoT. I have just gone through Azure IoT hub, iBOT etc.

How will I enable communication between my serial port with IoT hub?

Is there any supporting device for that?

Comment: You will have to get some application to bridge Azure and the serial port on your computer.  If the device does not provide any networking ability (i.e. wifi), there is no way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another device as a gateway, this device is networkable and has serial port. [Azure IoT Edg](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-v1/blob/master/v1/README.md#azure-iot-edge)e lets you build IoT solutions tailored to your exact scenario. You can refer to the document and get start.

In addition, here is a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-firmware-update) to implement a device firmware update process. This tutorial shows how you can start and monitor the firmware update process remotely through a back-end application connected to your hub.
[image]